# (SAP B1) - How to add user fields on Project Management?

Tags: project-management, sapb1

I'am adding a project (OPMG) using the above code and it's working perfectly.

```
SAPbobsCOM.CompanyService oCompServ = (SAPbobsCOM.CompanyService)oCompany.GetCompanyService();
SAPbobsCOM.ProjectManagementService pmgService = (SAPbobsCOM.ProjectManagementService)oCompServ.GetBusinessService(SAPbobsCOM.ServiceTypes.ProjectManagementService);
SAPbobsCOM.PM_ProjectDocumentData project = (SAPbobsCOM.PM_ProjectDocumentData)pmgService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.ProjectManagementServiceDataInterfaces.pmsPM_ProjectDocumentData);

project.ProjectName = "ProjectByDI_01";
project.Owner = 1;
project.StartDate = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1);
project.DueDate = new DateTime(2016, 11, 30);
project.ClosingDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 31);
project.ProjectType = SAPbobsCOM.ProjectTypeEnum.pt_External;
project.BusinessPartner = "C20000";
project.ContactPerson = 2;
project.Territory = 1;
project.SalesEmployee = 5;
project.AllowSubprojects = SAPbobsCOM.BoYesNoEnum.tYES;
project.ProjectStatus = SAPbobsCOM.ProjectStatusTypeEnum.pst_Started;
project.FinancialProject = "PRJ01";
project.RiskLevel = SAPbobsCOM.RiskLevelTypeEnum.rlt_High;
project.Industry = 1;
project.Reason = "Test comment";
project.AttachmentEntry = 1;

pmgService.AddProject(project);
```

But now, i need to add an user field into that Project too. However I don't know how to do that, once there's no "UserField" properties on that object.

Is anybody pass through this situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what SAP Business One version you are using but it must be version 9.2 or below.

User Defined Fields have been implemented for “PM_ProjectDocumentData”, “PM_StageData”, “PM_SubprojectDocumentData” for SAP Business One Version 9.3 PL01 and above.

For 9.3, `"project.UserFields."` will be exposed.

See link: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/28/project-management-object-is-exposed-from-sap-business-one-version-92-pl03/

Comment: Thank's for the answer, i forgot to say that i'm using SAP 92. I will upgrade to SAP 93 and try to use it